# How can I group an array of objects by key and create another object inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

Does anyone know how to group an array of objects by an object key and then create a new array of objects based on the grouping? For example, I have an array of Build objects as below and I want to group by products and create another object of colors and price based on that.

```
build = [
    {
        'Product': 'Cabinets',
        'Color': 'Blue',
    }, 
    {
        'Product': 'CounterTop',
        'Color': 'White',
    }, 
    {
        'Product': 'Cabinets',
        'Color': 'Yellow',
    }, 
    {
        'Product': 'Cabinets',
        'Color': 'Yellow',
    }
]
```

And I want it like this

```
[
  {
     'Product':'Cabinet',
     'color' : { 'Blue','Yellow' }
  },
  {
     'Product':'CounterTop',
     'color' : { 'White' }
  }
]
```

I wrote a code to archive it but I am not getting the result as expected.

```html
build.forEach(pr => {
                if (pr.Product in result) {
                    result[pr['Product']]['Color'] = pr['Color'];
                }
                else {
                    result[pr['Product']] = {
                        'Product': pr['Product'],
                        'Color': pr['Color'] 
                    }
                }
            });
```

Above code returns

```
 [
  {
     'Product':'Cabinet',
     'color' : 'Yellow' 
  },
  {
     'Product':'CounterTop',
     'color' : 'White'
  }
]
```

Comment: You are overwriting the first occurrence with the second with `result[pr['Product']]['Color'] = pr['Product']`.  You need to Array.push or use array spread to update any existing array assigned to `Color`

Comment: change `Color` to be an array in your output. In your example `Color` is an object which expects a key-value pair.

Comment: @DaveMeehan I tried .push but I am getting an error saying "push is not a function". Could you please write an example?

Comment: Hi @chris, can you please tell me how do I change Color to be an array?

Comment: Have some concerns on the **expected output**. **1)** As pointed out by others `color: { "blue", "yellow" }` is not a valid structure. May be it should be: `color: ["blue", "yellow"]`. Next, **2)** The string `"Cabinets"` (plural) becomes `"Cabinet"` in expected output. Is this a typo & it should actually be `"Cabinets"` in both `build` & expected-output?. And, finally **3)** There are two `"Yellow"` cabinets in `build` - but only one in expected-output. Do you need to remove duplicates - or was it a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expecting `'color' : { 'Blue','Yellow' }` in your output is wrong. Objects are key-value pairs of data.

Instead, you want `color` to be an array. I adjusted your code:

```
build.forEach(pr => {
  if (pr.Product in result) {
      result[pr['Product']]['Color'].push(pr['Color']);
  } else {
      result[pr['Product']] = {
          'Product': pr['Product'],
          'Color': [pr['Color']]
      }
  }
});
```

Now think about how you can prevent duplicate values in the array. @Lissy93's answer helps with that by using `findIndex`.

Comment: So I am debugging this code and  'if (!result[pr['Product']]['Color'])' is false every time

Comment: You are right, @Rnue. Actually, doing that check is not necessary I updated my answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version. Hope it helps :)

```js
const builds = [
    { 'Product': 'Cabinets', 'Color': 'Blue' }, 
    { 'Product': 'CounterTop', 'Color': 'White' }, 
    { 'Product': 'Cabinets', 'Color': 'Yellow' }, 
    { 'Product': 'Cabinets', 'Color': 'Yellow' }
];

const results = [];

builds.forEach((build) => {
  const index = results.findIndex((b) => b.Product === build.Product);
  if (index === -1) {
    results.push({Product: build.Product, Color: [ build.Color ]});
  } else {
    results[index] = {Product: build.Product, Color: [ ...results[index].Color, build.Color ]}
  }
});

console.log(results);
```

The main issue in your code, was that you're mixing up arrays and key-value-pairs for `color`. KVP's look like `{ color: 'red' }`, whereas arrays would be: `[ 'red', 'blue']`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this strategy:

- Find unique products
- Based on the unique products use `Array#map` and `Array#filter` to build desired data

See demo below:

```js
const builds = [ { 'Product': 'Cabinets', 'Color': 'Blue' }, { 'Product': 'CounterTop', 'Color': 'White' }, { 'Product': 'Cabinets', 'Color': 'Yellow' }, { 'Product': 'Cabinets', 'Color': 'Yellow' } ],

      output = [...new Set(builds.map(({Product}) => Product))]
      .map(Product =>
          ({
              Product, 
              Color:builds.filter(({Product:P}) => P === Product)
              .map(({Color}) => Color)
           })
       );

console.log(output);
```